# How can I query a table by its proterty's specific value when the property is a list?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, filtering, navigation-properties

I have a class named `Quote` and `QuoteInfo`. And the `Quote` class has a `List` of `QuoteInfo`. Like this:

```
public class Quote
{   
    ...
    public virtual List<QuoteInfo> QuoteInfo { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Also my `QuoteInfo` class has a `Language` property. Like this:

```
public class QuoteInfo
{
    ...
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

As you can see when I query my `Quotes` like this...

```
    var quotes = dbContext.Quotes.ToList();
```

... all the `QuoteInfo`s come with it (lazy loading enabled of course). But i just want to get the `QuoteInfo`s with a specific language. How can I do that in one query?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: For example I have a Quote with 2 QuoteInfos. What I want to do is getting Quote and the QuoteInfo list containing the one with the specific language, which would be 1 Quote and its QuoteInfo list's count is 1.

Comment: `dbContext.Quotes.ToList()` will only load all Quotes. The QouteInfos are only loaded when you use the NavigationProperty `QuoteInfo` of the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var quotes = dbContext.Quotes
    .Select(x=>new 
     { 
         Quote=x, 
         QuouteInfos=x.QuoteInfo.Where(y=>y.Language==myPreferedLanguage) 
     });
```

it will select it to new List where you have `Quoute` and `QouteInfos` which are only in `myPreferedLanguage`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I think that query gets all Quotes where any of its QuoteInfos' language is myPreferredLanguage because it returned the same result.

What I'm lookng for is getting all Quotes and filtering their QuoteInfos by their Language.

Comment: That worked but it only returns QuoteInfo property of the Quote, I think because of select. What can I do to load other properties too?

Comment: @MustafaKarakuş There are other properties of `Quoute` for e.g. `qoutes.First().Quoute.Text`

Comment: Yes there are other properties too. I don't think adding these properties to Select statement would be very efficent. What else can I do to load them all?

Comment: @MustafaKarakuş you are not adding them to select, you can access them from object returned from select

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the QuoteInfo entities directly using the DbContext if you want to apply filtering.

```
int quoteId = ; // Id of the Quote you want to get the infos
var myLanguage = ;  // lange of the infos you want to get

var infos = dbContext.QuoteInfos.Where(p=>p.QuoteId == quoteId && p.Language == myLanguage);
```

Using NavigationProperties (in your case `QuoteInfo`) will allways load the whole related entities and any addtional filtering using a `Where` statement is applied in memory.

**Update:**
When i understand you comment right, you want to get all Quotes where an info of the Quote matches a specific language. For this case you can use the following query.

```
var languageDependantQuote = from quote in dbContext.Quotes 
                             from info in quote.QuoteInfos 
                             where info.Language == myLanguage 
                             select quote;
```

Comment: But what I want to do is getting Quotes with these QuoteInfos, not just QuoteInfos. Or should I just remove virtual property to disable lazy loading and just set the QuoteInfo property of the Quotes the filtered values which i acquire with your query? I think that would damage performance.

Comment: @MustafaKarakuş you mean a query like that `from quote in dbContext.Quotes from info in quote.QuoteInfos where info.Language == myLanguage select quote`

Comment: I'm sorry that i wasn't specific enough. I meant I want to get Quotes and their QuoteInfos which has with a specific language. For example I have a Quote with 2 QuoteInfos. What I want to do is getting Quote and the QuoteInfo list containing the one with the specific language, which would be 1 Quote and its QuoteInfo list's count is 1. I should add this example to main post actually :)

Comment: @MustafaKarakuş that is not possible, cause NavigationProperties will always contain all related entities, so you need to apply the filtering in memory using `quote.QouteInfos.Where(p=>p.Language == myLanguage)`.

Comment: I understand and thank you for your answer. I was just worried about performance, because fetching all QuoteInfos with the Quote(while I only need specific ones) seemed ineffective. But if that is not possible, I guess there is nothing to do :)

Comment: @MustafaKarakuş take a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694259/filtering-navigation-properties-in-ef-code-first i think there is a solution to your problem

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at that.