# Navigation property with two foreign keys where one is hard-coded

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

We have a table `RequestApproval` that uses two fields to determine uniquness: `RequestType` and `RequestDetailID`. Each type of request has its own details table whose primary key maps to the `RequestDetailID` of the approval table. There's nothing to prevent two request detail tables from having overlapping IDs. That's why the `RequestType` field is part of the unique constraint. This was to avoid having a separate approvals table for each type of request.

We are trying to configure the request detail table to have a navigation property to its approvals. Originally, we configured the navigation property like this:

```
        HasMany(r => r.RequestApprovals)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(q => q.RequestDetailId);
```

Unfortunately, this grabs the approvals for all request types. There doesn't appear to be a way to tell Entity Framework to limit the results to just those with a specific `RequestType`.

Can I tell EF to additionally filter by request type? Even if I had to modify the LINQ query to explicitly filter, that'd be fine. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a way to augment a `.Include` to filter out results.

Comment: I found this answer, but it is nasty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694259/filtering-navigation-properties-in-ef-code-first